# What is the advantage of a pair C++ swap method?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given,

```
auto a = make_pair(1,"one");
auto b = make_pair(2,"two");
a.swap(b);
```

When do I really need to use `a.swap(b)` when there is a more generalized `std::swap(a,b)` that works the same way.

Comment: My guess is that `std::swap<std::pair>()` is implemented using `std::pair::swap()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::swap(a, b)` is specialized for `std::pair` to call `a.swap(b)` internally.  `std::swap()` has many container-specific specializations so it can use container-appropriate methods for the actual swapping.

If you are writing code for a specific type, consider using `a.swap(b)` directly (or whatever method is appropriate for that type).

If you are writing code that is generic for multiple types, use `std::swap()` instead, and let the compiler work out which specialization(s) to call.

Comment: Even better for generic code, enable ADL, to allow any lvalues satisfying the Swappable concept: `{ using std::swap; swap(a, b); }`